# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on boolean variable from separate class

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to develop game scenario that able to trigger the alarm with alarm light and siren audio to play. For the testing purpose I set it that to boolean value as "alarmOn" in AlarmLight class.

```
**AlarmLight.cs**
public class AlarmLight : MonoBehaviour {

public float fadeSpeed = 2f;
public float highIntensity = 2f;
public float lowIntensity = 0.5f;
public float changeMargin = 0.2f;
public bool alarmOn = false;

private float targetIntensity;
public Light light;


//add alarm lights
// tag as siren
void Awake()
{
    light.intensity = 0f;
    targetIntensity = highIntensity;
}

void Update()
{
    if (alarmOn==true)
    {
        light.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(light.intensity, targetIntensity,fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        ChecktargetIntensity();
    }
    else
    {
        light.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(light.intensity, 0f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}

void ChecktargetIntensity()
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(targetIntensity - light.intensity) < changeMargin)
    {
        if (targetIntensity==highIntensity)
        {
            targetIntensity = lowIntensity;
        }
        else
        {
            targetIntensity = highIntensity;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I  tried to access that value with LastPlayerSight class and for the testing purpose i was trying to return false as below.

```
alarm.alarmOn = (playerPosition != resetPlayerPosition);
```

Then I tried to play my scene, and I got the error which is the problem with above line of code.

[image]

This is my LastPlayerSight.cs class

```
public class LastPlayerSight : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 playerPosition = new Vector3(1000f, 1000f, 1000f);
public Vector3 resetPlayerPosition = new Vector3(1000f, 1000f, 1000f);

public float lightHighIntensity = 0.25f;
public float lightLowIntensity = 0f;
public float fadeSpeed =7f;

public float musicFadeSpeed = 1f;

//directional alarmlight ref
private AlarmLight alarm;

//main directional light ref
private Light mainLight;

private AudioSource panicAudio;

//siren audio
private AudioSource[] sirens;

void Awake()
{
    alarm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(Tags.alarms).GetComponent<AlarmLight>();
    mainLight = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(Tags.mainLight).GetComponent<Light>();

    GameObject[] sirenAttachedGameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(Tags.siren);
    sirens = new AudioSource[sirenAttachedGameObjects.Length];



    for(int i = 0; i<sirens.Length; i++)
    {
        sirens[i] = sirenAttachedGameObjects[i].GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
}

void Update()
{
    SwitchAlarms();
    MusicFading();
}

void SwitchAlarms()
{
    alarm.alarmOn = (playerPosition != resetPlayerPosition);

    float newIntensity;

    if(playerPosition != resetPlayerPosition)
    {
        newIntensity = lightLowIntensity;
    }
    else
    {
        newIntensity = lightHighIntensity;
    }

    mainLight.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(mainLight.intensity, newIntensity,fadeSpeed*Time.deltaTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < sirens.Length; i++)
    {
        if (playerPosition != resetPlayerPosition)
        {
            sirens[i].Play();
        }
        else
        {
            sirens[i].Stop();
        }
    }
}

void MusicFading()
{
   //AudioSource audioTemp = audio.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    if (playerPosition != resetPlayerPosition)
    {
        //audio.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = Mathf.Lerp(audio.volume, 0f, musicFadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        panicAudio.volume = Mathf.Lerp(panicAudio.volume, 0.8f, musicFadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    else
    {
        panicAudio.volume = Mathf.Lerp(panicAudio.volume, 0.0f, musicFadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

}

I'm beginner of developing such things and can anyone guide me to correct the problem?

Comment: Can you add the SwitchAlarms () method?

Comment: It is Included in LastPlayerSight.cs class

Comment: Check  float newIntensity = 0.0f;

Comment: Its adding more errors -[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.RotateView () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:237)
UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController.Update () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs:64)]

Comment: We have a "go to" question for this exception, please take a look at it to help you debug the issue.